# Type of conditional expression cannot be determined

Tags: c#, int

i am trying to save value from dataset to List here is my code

```
GetPostWRTPager_Class = ds.Tables[0]
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(r => new GetPostWRTPager() {
     IsApproved = r["IsApproved"] == DBNull.Value 
       ? DBNull.Value 
       : Convert.ToInt32(r["IsApproved"]),
     ApprovedBy = r["ApprovedBy"],
     ApprovedOn = Convert.ToDateTime(r["ApprovedOn"]), })
  .ToList();
```

it is always giving me error defined below

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'int'

what is wrong in my code

Comment: is approves is the int  value? or bit value?

Comment: IsApprove is int value
1) approve
2) Disapprove
3) Pending

Comment: is your `GetPostWRTPager.IsApproved` nullable?

Comment: @GeomanYabes yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is no implicit conversion between `DBNull` and `int`. But you could use the `Field` extension method that supports nullable types(better than using `System.Object`):

```
IsApproved = r.Field<int?>("IsApproved"),
```

If you can't change that property to make it an `int?` you have to cast the `int` to `object`:

```
IsApproved = r.IsNull("IsApproved") ? DBNull.Value : (object)r.Field<int>("IsApproved"),
```

If you want an `int` value and 0 in case it's `NULL`:

```
IsApproved = r.Field<int?>("IsApproved").GetValueOrDefault(),
```

If `IsApproved` actually is a `bool` property(what the name suggests) and only 1 means `true`:

```
IsApproved = r.Field<int?>("IsApproved") == 1,
```